# Problema com acentuações no vue-json-excel

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Estou utilizando o `vue-json-excel` para exportar uma planilha do Excel (eu tenho a tabela na minha tela e uso ele para exportar os mesmos dados para excel).

Até ai, tudo funciona perfeitamente, porem, tive problemas com acentuações. Exemplo, o `não`, aparece `NÃ£o`, e assim em diante.

```
    <download-excel
        class   = "btn btn-default"
        :data   = "data.resultado"
        :fields = "json_fields"
        :meta   = "json_meta"
        name    = "filename.xls" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    </download-excel>
```

**JS**

```
data(){
            return{
                data: {},
                filterTerm: '',
                json_fields : {},
                json_data: [],
                json_meta: [
                    [{
                        "key": "charset",
                        "value": "utf8"
                    }]
                ]
            }
        },
```

Os dados estão vindo do banco, e na tela, são exibidos corretamente.

Dessa maneira, eu faço para inserir os dados do meu banco em um `objeto`

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.data.titulos.length; i++){
                        this.json_fields[this.data.titulos[i]] = "String"
                    }
```

**JSON RETORNO**

```
{
   "titulos":[
      "Data Emissão",
      "Data Saída",
      "CAMPO 3",
      "CAMPO 4"
   ],
   "resultado":[
      [
         "Carta Correção",
         "Não",
         "Não ",
         "09/08/2017 17:56"
      ],
      [
         "Solicita Alteração",
         "Não",
         "Não ",
         "09/08/2017 17:56"
      ],
      [
         "UM",
         464752,
         "UM ",
         "09/08/2017 17:56"
      ],
      [
         "UM",
         464752,
         "UM ",
         "09/08/2017 17:56"
      ]
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O teu problema parece-me somente um erro de digitação.

Muda

```
"value": "utf8"
```

para

```
"value": "utf-8"
```

**jsFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/s8wemmyL/

Comment: Eu tinha testado, testei de todas as maneiras, ai abri o arquivo do `node_modules/...` e comparei com o arquivo que está no `github` deles, e vi que ele não estava recebendo a `prop` meta. Ai consegui resolver da forma a cima. Mas valeu mesmo assim Sergio, voce sempre me ajuda rs ;)

Comment: @RafaelAugusto eu usei o teu código integral, só acrescentei o `-` em `utf8`:)

Comment: @RafaelAugusto acabei por mandar uma sugestão para lá :) https://github.com/jecovier/vue-json-excel/pull/10

Comment: sabe me dizer o porque da `erro` quando eu tento exportar uma tabela com muitos dados? se eu faço com poucos, baixa normal, se meu `json` tem muitos dados, fica baixando (mas nunca baixa, nem inicia ou mostra nos downloads, mas se você tenta fechar o navegador, diz que tem um download em andamento).

Comment: @RafaelAugusto não faço ideia. Talvez haja algum caractere nos dados que faz o programa parar.

Comment: Estranho porque só é com boa quantidade de registro, mas vou dar uma analisada, depois volto para deixar feedback. Abraços

Answer (score 0):

Depois de muito trabalho (nem tanto) eu descobri o erro e vou deixar aqui para aqueles que passarem pelo mesmo que eu.
O `modulo` possui o `:meta` para receber os parametros, porem, quando você instala o `modulo`, ex: `npm install --save vue-json-excel` e olha no codigo fonte, voce vê que ele não recebe os parametros. E para isso, uma solução simples é...

```
<template>
    <a
        href="#"
        :id="id_name"
        @click="generate_excel">
        <slot>
            {{button_text}}
        </slot>
    </a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function(){
        return {
            animate   : true,
            animation : '',
        }
    },
    props: {
        'button_text': {
            type: String,
            default: "Download Excel"
        },
        'data':{
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },
        'fields':{
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
        'name':{
            type: String,
            default: "data.xls"
        },
        'meta':{
            type: Array,
            default: []
        }
    },
    created: function () {
    },
    computed:{
        id_name : function(){
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            return 'export_'+now;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        emitXmlHeader: function () {
            var headerRow =  '<tr>\n';
            for (var colName in this.fields) {
                headerRow += '  <th>\n';
                headerRow += colName + '\n';
                headerRow += '  </th>\n';
            }
            headerRow += '</tr>\n';
            var metatags = null;
            this.meta.forEach(function(element) {
                metatags += '<meta '
                element.forEach(function(m) {
                    metatags += m.key+'="'+m.value+'" ';
                });
                metatags += '>';
            });
            return '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head>'+metatags+'<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>Data</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>\n' +
                   '<thead>\n\n' +
                   headerRow+
                   '</thead>\n\n'+
                   '</tbody>\n';
        },
        emitXmlFooter: function() {
            return '\n</tbody>\n' +
                    '</table>\n'+
                    '</body>\n'+
                   '</html>\n';
        },
        jsonToHtml: function (jsonObject) {
            var row;
            var col;
            var xml;
            // console.log(jsonObject);
            var data = typeof jsonObject != "object"
                     ? JSON.parse(jsonObject)
                     : jsonObject;
            xml = this.emitXmlHeader();
            for (row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
                xml += '<tr>\n';
                for (col in data[row]) {
                    xml += '  <td>\n';
                    xml += String(data[row][col])+ '\n';
                    xml += '  </td>\n';
                }
                xml += '</tr>\n';
            }
            xml += this.emitXmlFooter();
            return xml;
        },
        generate_excel: function (){
            var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            var a = document.getElementById(this.id_name);
            a.href = uri + base64(this.jsonToHtml(this.data));
            a.download = this.name;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```